# Footnote mark appears too big in tufte-book + xelatex

Tags: xetex, footnotes, tufte-book

when trying to put a footnote in tufte-book with xelatex, the number on the text appears too big, not with the usual scriptsize. While the actual sidenote appears correctly formatted, as does a number written with \textsuperscript. If I change the compiler to pdflatex, the problem disappears.

Here is the code:

```
%! TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass{tufte-book}

\begin{document}
    a\textsuperscript{1}
    b\footnote{c} % This one appears bigger
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: well for a reason that I don't know the class uses lmodern with xelatex and the fonts are different. You could use lualatex instead, the font setup there looks better.

Comment: In this case, I think it doesn't have to do with the font, it happens the same if I change the font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tufte-book` class defines the footnotemark as follows:

```
> \@makefnmark=macro:
->\hbox {\@textsuperscript {\normalfont \footnotesize \@thefnmark }}.
```

So: footnotesize inside superscript. Footnotesize is a rather complex calculation, which differs a little bit from default superscript.

Note that this is also the case with pdflatex and lualatex, but there the class uses a different font so the effect is much smaller (but still visible on very large zoom levels).

To get a superscript that is the same size as the footnotes you can therefore use the same construct `\textsuperscript{\normalfont\footnotesize 123}` or conversely redefine `\@makefnmark`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{tufte-book}
\makeatletter
\def\@makefnmark{\textsuperscript{\@thefnmark}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    a\textsuperscript{1}\footnote{c}
    b\footnote{d}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Note that this redefinition could have side effects - the original definition is probably there for a reason. So check the output carefully.